# How to rename columns that have the same name?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to rename the column names, but the Data Frame contains similar column names. How do I rename them?

```
df.columns
```

Output:

```
Index([ 'Goods',
       'Durable goods','Services','Exports', 'Goods', 'Services', 'Imports', 'Goods', 'Services']
```

Here, there are three goods columns that have similar names. How can I rename a specific column?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: stackoverflow.com/questions/30650474.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df.columns = ['Goods_1', 'Durable goods','Services','Exports', 'Goods_2', 'Services', 'Imports', 'Goods_3', 'Services']
```

or if you have too many columns:

```
cols = []
count = 1
for column in df.columns:
    if column == 'Goods':
        cols.append(f'Goods_{count}')
        count+=1
        continue
    cols.append(column)
df.columns = cols
```

Comment: i'd say this is the simplest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: Is there any way to make it more dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

You can rename column name based on its position too:

```
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "new_col_name" })
```

Note: If you have similar columns names, all of them will be renamed.

Comment: doesn't worked for me.

Comment: The whole point is renaming columns with the same name, so this doesn't really help...

Comment: df.columns[1] will give a column name, and then it replaces all the columns with that name as "new_col_name" which defeats the whole purpose of this question. This answer is not useful